# Undefined limit $(0/0)$ for a function of two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the following limit:

$$  \lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to(1,1)}  \frac{c_1 \cdot (x_1^2-1)}{\frac{x_1^{10}}{x_2^2}-1}$$ where $c_1$is a constant.

This is giving $\frac{0}{0}$ and I can't seem a way to escape it.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a Taylor expansion around $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$, you will see that you can set $x_2=1$ without any problem. What is left is $c_1(x_1^2-1)/(x_1^10-1)$. If $x_1$ goes to $1$, then the limit is $c_1/5$. Is this of any help?

As Michael said, there is no problem setting $x_2=1$ ane then the problem reduces to $c_1 (x_1^2-1) / (x_1^{10} - 1)$ which is $c_1 / (1+x_1^2+x_1^4+x_1^6+x_1^8)$ then $c_1/5$.

Answer (score 0):

Approach along $x_1=1$, and the limit is 0.
Approach along $x_2=1$, and you can cancel $x_1^2-1$ from top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't understand your approach, cause, the limit I am interested in, is when both of $x_1$and $x_2$ tend to ZERO at the SAME time.

Comment: You can calculate a value for $f(x_1,1)$ that is not zero, and is also well-defined.  You can cancel $x_1^2-1$ from top and bottom, so the function is no longer $0/0$.  Then take the limit of that function as $x_1\to 1$.  On the other hand, approach along a different direction $f(1,x_2)=0$, so the limit as $x_2\to 1$ is 0.  If those two limits disagree, then the overall limit does not exist.  If they agree, you might need to approach along the direction $x=y$, so calculate $f(x_1,x_1)$ for $x_1\neq 1$, cancel $x_1^2-1$, and take the limit as $x_1\to 1$.

Comment: as a matter of fact, the two limits does not agree, since $c_1\neq0$..Thanks again for the help